# How do you divide surface area?

Tags: geometry, spheres, spherical-geometry

I am having difficulty trying to scale the surface area of a rectangle on a sphere.

I have tried many different things and have gotten many different answers. I am doing this with a worldbuilding project, but I thought coming here would be better because it is all pertaining to math. I have a world that is the same mass as Earth but with a radius that is 0.997x smaller. The radius of Earth is 6,371 km. The radius of this sphere is 6,348.7 km. I did some wonky math to find the surface area of the planet and got 950,333,068.1 km² with a radius of 8,696 km. It needs to be 508,286,627 km² with a radius of 6,348.7 km. If you divide the areas, you get a difference of 0.53485. You divide the radii, you get a difference of 0.734.

Would I use 0.734 to scale 950,333,068.1 km² down or 0.53485?

Comment: Let $r_{s}$ and $r_{e}$ be the radii of the earth and your sphere respectively. The surface area of a sphere is given as $4\pi r^2$, so by dividing the areas, what you are calculating is $r_{s}^2/r_{e}^2$, while division of the radii in themselves is $r_{s}/r_{e}$. You can check for yourself that $0.734^2$ is approximately equal to $0.53$.

Comment: @H.sapiensrex I just said words that would have me cut out of the will. I wasn't moving the squared symbol along with the answer. So all of my math was decent except for that. I would use 0.0.734^2 when scaling the other areas for the continents because they are all km squared. Thank you!

Comment: Though the ^2 on the area number and the 0.734 will cancel out wouldn't it?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that, sorry. 0.734 is simply the ratio of $r_{s}$ to $r_{e}$; it is a dimensionless quantity. Same with 0.53; it's just that same ratio squared. There are no physical units involved, squared or otherwise

Comment: @H.sapiensrex I misunderstood you when you said  0.734^2. If I was trying to scale the large number down, would I use 0.734 or 0.53?

Comment: I think I need more information lol. When you ask how you'd "scale the large number down", how much do you want to scale it by? Or are you asking how you go from 0.734 to 0.53? To what quantity (mass, radius, surface area etc) do you wish to apply the scaling?

Comment: wait, sorry yeah I just realised what it is you're asking. To convert from surface area on earth to surface area on your sphere yes, you would multiply the earth equivalent by 0.53. Another way of looking at it is that the earth surface area is $4\pi r_{e}^2$ while that of your sphere is $4\pi r_{s}^2$. To get to the latter from the former you need to cancel a factor of $r_{e}^2$ while introducing a factor of $r_{s}^2$; these are accomplished in a single step by multiplying through by $r_{s}^2/r_{e}^2$, which as we know is 0.53(ish)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146247/discussion-between-martamo-and-h-sapiens-rex).

Comment: Lengths scale with $r$, areas scale with $r^2$, volumes scale with $r^3$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Thank you. But sapiens rex helped me see that I was just being dumb and the answer was right in front of me.